# Late night taxis from San Jose Airport, Costa Rica (SJO)?

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, costa-rica, sjo

In a few weeks, I have a flight arriving in to San Jose airport (SJO, Alajuela) very late at night (a little after 1am).

Can I expect to still find taxis there at that time of night?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like [at least one shuttle service](http://www.easyridecr.com/private.htm) stops their regular service at 8pm, but continues [a night shuttle service](http://www.easyridecr.com/private.htm) until 5am.

However, [TaxiAeropuerto](http://www.taxiaeropuerto.com/index.php?lang=en) (the bright orange taxis) offer 24/7 taxi service from the airport.  I apologise if you can't read Spanish, mine isn't so great, but a rough translation of the last two sentences on that page is all you need:

> Likewise, we transfer to the airport. We offer 24 hours service, 7
>   days a week

I imagine calling them to reserve might be a way to guarantee a pickup, but otherwise yeah, it sounds like you'll have no problem there.